# Blazor WASM - Link to file on .Server from .Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM project with 3 solutions: App.Client, App.Server, and App.Shared. I want to put a link `<a href="path_to_file"></a>` on a page in App.Client that can link to a file in App.Server/files/file.txt. How can I do this? I'm surprised something so simple is so complicated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You've stated what you want to accomplish. But not what's preventing you from accomplishing it. What's stopping you from creating the hyperlink? Can you show what you've tried as a [mcve] and clearly explain how it's not working?

Comment: What I did was place an <a href="../../Server/files/files.txt"></a> Link on the page, but when clicked that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I tried searching online but I'm amazed by the lack of solutions.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't do anything"? Does it point to the expected URL? Does visiting that URL give an error message? Please be clear, and edit your question to show exactly what you've tried and clearly explain how it's not meeting your needs.

Comment: It redirects me to https://localhost:5001/Server/files/file.txt, which is just a blank page

Comment: Okay, so is that the URL where you expect the file to be accessible at? If so, please edit your question to show the configuration you've done in order to allow the file to be accessed at that URL so we can debug why it's not showing up. And clarify "blank page" for us. What does your browser's dev tools tell you? Do you get a 404?

Comment: Here, I'll just place a screenshot of the code + project structure so you can understand what I'm trying to do. [link](https://prnt.sc/1ri7mcr). And I don't get a 404. The browser's dev tools doesn't tell me anything either. It's literally just a blank page.

Comment: Also, I'm new to Blazor and have no clue, so a removal of the downvote would be apprpeciated.

Comment: Please do not ask people to vote in a particular way - votes are there to use as the voter sees fit. I am unable to access the link, and in case your question needs to contain all necessary information in order to address the question. If you want to server static content from an ASP.NET Core site, you need to show the steps you've taken to serve that static content. That means explain in your question where the file is, and show where you've wired the host up to serve static content. If you don't know how to do these things, then research static content hosting in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the Server to specifically *allow* it. The "no until asserted otherwise" attitude is a security feature.

When you have a "Files" folder in your Server project, add this piece of code:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();                     // leave this one in
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
  System.IO.Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "FiLes" )),  
  RequestPath = "/files"
});
```

The StaticFileOptions let you control which extensions to allow etc. And then this should work:

```
<a href="/files/sample.html"></a>
```

Comment: Sorry, where exactly do I add this piece of code? I'm new to Blazor, sorry

Comment: In Server.Startup (or Program.cs in net6). You already have the first line.

Comment: Also, is it possible to make the server "yes until asserted otherwise"? Just curious. Thanks again.

Comment: You shouldn't want to.

Comment: But just for the sake of knowledge, is there a way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: You are right that there is no reason to do it though.